# Safe way to initialize a Plugin that depends on Project settings

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm writing a SublimeText Plugin that uses a shelf for persistent storage of some data; the path of the shelf file is defined in the settings of the current project. I have a WindowCommand and a keybinding for it that initializes the class that holds the shelf, but I want to automatically execute this on startup if a suitable project is open.

Simply running the command when the plugin is loaded fails because `sublime.active_window()` is still uninitialized - my current workaround is to use `set_timeout` with a (hopefully) large enough timeout:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

_data = None

class MkshelfCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        global _data
        shelf_path = self.window.active_view().settings().get("shelf_path")
        if shelf_path:
            _data = MyClass(shelf_path)

sublime.set_timeout(lambda: sublime.active_window().run_command("mkshelf"), 1000)
```

This is obviously all kinds of bad; but I couldn't figure out how to do this more reliably as I could neither find a way to access the current projects settings without a view, nor a method to ensure the window exists before executing the command so I could get rid of the timeout (I've thought of abusing `EventListener.on_activated`, but this seems even more ugly than what I'm doing right now). Is there a better way to do this or should I just bite the bullet and stick with my current approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `sublime.active_window()` directly in you timeout callback, call a function that calls itself when `active_window()` is still `None`:

```
def runCommandWhenInitialized():
    activeWindow = sublime.active_window()
    if activeWindow is not None:
        activeWindow.run_command("mkshelf")
    else:
        sublime.set_timeout(lambda: runCommandWhenInitialized(), 100)


sublime.set_timeout(lambda: runCommandWhenInitialized(), 100)
```

(I didn't actually run this code, but I think it should work.)

Comment: I had hoped for something that would feel less like a hack, but it seems SublimeText doesn't offer anything better do deal with a situation like this (which seems to be normal for half of my use cases, like "close a view"). I chose to accept your solution as it is a reasonably safe refinement of my code and should suffice as a workaround.

Comment: I agree, I wish there was a "sublime has finished booting up, restored all windows and loaded all plugins" event. I have needed that in a couple of instances.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a module level method called plugin_loaded. It might
only work in Sublime 3. I don't know which one you're using.

def plugin_loaded():
   pass

http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html